# JavaScript lookbehind until whitespace with capture group

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to get a capture group and up to space character. Capture groups should look like

```
[ "NOW", "NOW()","(",undefined,")" ];

//regex of now
d.match(/(?<=(.*))?(\()(.*)?(\))/);
```

Here is what I am testing as of right now

```
google NOW(time);
```

Just for practice purposes.

Here is my explanation of each capture group that I believe is what it is.

**Lookbehind**

```
(?<=(.*))
```

**Not needed but can happen**

```
?
```

**First Parenthesis**

```
(\()
```

**Inside Parenthesis, but not needed if not exists**

```
(.*)?
```

**Last Parenthesis**

```
(\))
```

As of right now I am getting a invalid regular expression error. I just need

```
NOW(time);
```

out of

```
google NOW(time);
```

Like above.

Any help in getting this regex to work appropriately

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds.

Comment: What Felix said, but you can use `\b` to test for word boundaries.  `/\b(\w+\([^\;]*\;)/` ought to do it I think.

Comment: Well that's a wonderful thing to know, hopefully ECMAScript 6 will support it. Any word in the standardizations?

Comment: In the most recent draft (Oct 2014), no support for look-behind. They finally added support for matching UTF-16 code point, rather than matching UTF-16 units

Comment: Oh man we need to kick these guys into gear I suppose.